# VSTS Build Server "Get Sources" failing GIT Version null - iOS build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an iOS build which has been working for the 8 months and all of a suddenly it stopped working and I'm getting the following error on the very first step - Get Sources (this project) :

```
2017-10-04T04:46:23.4760890Z ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
2017-10-04T04:46:23.8015160Z Syncing repository: AppCentre (TfsGit)
2017-10-04T04:46:23.8278500Z ##[command]git version
2017-10-04T04:46:26.2449280Z ##[error]Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: _version
2017-10-04T04:46:26.2589190Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
```

The Android and Web Page builds are all working fine just not this one.

Haven't changed anything to the build template.

I've also tried building previous commits and other branches which have built succesfully in the past but still getting the same error.

Comment: What's the build agent did you use? And can you show the detail log by setting `system.debug` as `true`?

Comment: Did you make any changes to your Mac that is running the build?  That error seems like an issue from git on your mac.  Also which agent version?

Comment: I forgot to reply to this, I found out it was an issue on my Mac after an xcode update.   Accepted the T&Cs on the xcode update, restarted the computer and everything was working fine again :)